# Automatic Rotating Platform

Tags: motor

I would like to build a very simple, circular wooden platform that rotates automatically - no stopping.  The torque is not very important, as it doesn't need to support much weight.  As far as rpm, not too fast, but not incredibly slow - about the pace of a fast escalator?  That's the only comparison I can make.  It's for an art project.  I know this is probably an easy one for most people, but I am starting from square one.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: oh yeah and the platform is about 2-3 feet diameter

Comment: Where is the electronics problem?  This sounds like a mechanical problem, which is off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just buy a record turntable? Stick a 3 foot platform on it. It's kind of fast, and doesn't support much weight.

Or get a small motor off eBay, and make your own.

[image: Turntable]

You just need some bearings to hold the turntable, and a belt to connect the small wheel on the motor to the big wheel on the turntable.

Comment: I love sliding a sneaky answer into an off-topic question.

Comment: Unfortunately that teaches some unfortunate things.  We close questions for a reason.  Providing answers when you know the question will be closed partially defeats the purpose.

Comment: It's funny that this question is almost identical to the one you [just answered](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/44978/1024).

Comment: There was some electronic content in that question, which I answered.  Also note that nobody is trying to close that question, whereas this one got closed quickly.